# Facebook Android How to upload picture on Facebook Wall using Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to upload pictures on the wall of Facebook using Android platform.

I downloaded the Facebook SDK for Android, and I am working with this. Afortunally I found a several codes to do it, but didn´t works, some of them have AsyncFacebookRunner but I have not this class on the FB SDK, Do you know when I can use a simple code to do it? with a project?

Thanks,
Andrés

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some code to

```
private final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

 /*  and the below code to add image   */

JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
    media.put("type", "image");
    media.put("src", image);  // where 'image' is the image url or path stored in your device

    attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());

mFacebook.dialog(mActivity, "stream.publish", params,
                        new SampleDialogListener());
}
```

add this too

```
public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
                mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());

                } else {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "No wall post made");
            }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am a bit confused, I have to use JSON?

Comment: and what is the SampleDialogListener?

Comment: I added BaseDialogListener.java to the project.
Regarding this line:
mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());

What is mASyngRunner? and What is WallPostRequestListener? I have to add more classes to the project?

Comment: yes, download whole package and classes for facebook from github

Comment: yes, I downloaded the package of Facebook, and I created a new project called com_facebook_android with the following classes:
AsynFacebookRunner
Dialogerror
Facebook
FacebookError
FbDialog
Util
I have to add BaseDialogListener and UpdateStatusResultDialog to this project to?

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook developer site fore more information.Hackbook.java file has already explained it very well. this[Hackbook.java](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/#photo)